# ASP.NET MVC how to handle empty option in bootstrap dropdown list

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap theme to create views for my controller's actions. As I am using bootstrap theme it uses raw html code instead of @html tag helper methods so I want to stick with that. I am using asp-items attribute to populate my dropdownlist. here is my code

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" asp-for="@Model.MembershipTypes" >MemberShip Type</label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.Customer.MembershipTypeId"  class ="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes.Select(o=>o.name)))"  ></select>
        </div>
```

when I run the application dropdown list works as I want but the first option in list is empty [image]

this is what I get as result how can I fix this using html attributes

Comment: That's likely nothing to do with Bootstrap, I think it's all to do with your `new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes.Select(o=>o.name))` expression. Please post your **rendered** HTML of the `<select>` element, showing all of the `<option>` elements.

Comment: oh  after your comment I checked my selectlist method again with debug it turns out I have a row with null value for my dropdown list data.Thank you for your time